# failed_to_pick_backend from GCP Loadbalancer even healthy backend

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a GKE Cluster with the GCP Load Balancer as my Ingress Controller.

However, I noticed that a specific request to the service hosted in this GKE Cluster was being rejected with and 502 error.

I checked the GCP Loadbalancer logs and I was able to see a return with `statusDetails: "failed_to_pick_backend"`.

The health field is saying that my backend is healthy. Just to make sure I changed the health check type from HTTP to TCP to see if anything would change but it kept green.

So, what can I be missing if my GCP Loadbalancer is saying that my backend is reachable but at the same time it returns me an failed to pick backend message?

I really appreciate some help on that.

My ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-app
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: my-app-managed-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: my-app-svc
      port:
        number: 3000
```

My service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort
```

Running `kubectl describe pod <my-pod>` I can see

```
Conditions:
  Type                                       Status
  cloud.google.com/load-balancer-neg-ready   True 
  Initialized                                True 
  Ready                                      True 
  ContainersReady                            True 
  PodScheduled                               True
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue during updating of my deployment where the replicas property is set to 1 (haven't tested with a greater number yet). It only seems to last for a few seconds and then resolves itself. I haven't set an explicit health check, but the one that is created has a Timeout of 1s and Interval of 5s.

Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify the timer of your health check? If this is set to 1 second or lower than the health checks that were set to higher value, `failed_to_pick_backend` error will normally occur.

I recommend you to change the timer to the default value 5 or higher and then test a new deployment. You can check more details about the health check timers on this link[1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts

Comment: These are my configs so far in the LB Health Check: Interval - 15s and Timeout 15s. In my Backend, which is attached to that LB I have a timeout of 30s. From what I saw from docs the LB Timeout has to be less than LB Interval. Did I miss something in this config?

Comment: Can you start with the default of 5 seconds and let us know if it will fix the issue?